# Positioning element to exact div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm facing I think odd problem. I have website http://www.spacemind.ggpro.pl/ar/ and I'm trying to make this top menu (black rectangle) Stick to the left side of my Wrapper div.

```
<div style="z-index:9999;background-color:#000;right:0px;width:80%;position:absolute;margin: 0px auto;height:100px;color:#fff;">
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I use value `width:80%` but I hope that there is some way to stick it to left side of wrapper. I want this menu to be always (no matter what resolution user uses) in the position as in the image below:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMLvO.jpg

Comment: You should create a wrapper which contains all elements on the site and give it a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div style="width:980px;margin:auto;position:relative;">
    <div style="z-index:9999;background-color:#000;right:0px;width:100%;position:absolute;margin: 0px auto;height:100px;color:#fff;">
        <div style="padding:20px;">
            <a href="index.html">
               <img src="img/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course inline styling is a bad idea. You should put it in some classes.

Comment: When I delete value right:0px; my menu goes all the way left, not to the point where wrapper starts. There is element <div class="row"> and I want align my menu to the left side of it.

Comment: I don't see any wrapper there. The parent is `body` tag. It worked few minutes ago. Did you change something? No '.row' element as well.

Comment: I'm trying to to put in code your suggestions. When I removed right:0px and replaced with left:0px. I got something like this:

http://i59.tinypic.com/106et6d.jpg

Comment: Row class below in the code:

<div id="howto" class="how wrap">
  
 <div class="row">

   <div class="col-lg-12">
   <span style="font-family: Arial;font-size:14px;">PRODUKTY</span></br></br>
   </div>

Comment: Update: I asked my friend to check how it works on his device and something is wrong :/

here's screenshot:

http://i62.tinypic.com/6zq8ib.jpg

Menu doesn't aling to the position where the word "PRODUKTY" starts...

Comment: I put this version on the server. Menu is in the center but I want extend it to the right. Position is correct, when I zoom in or zoom out, it doesn't move but stay in line with "PRODUKTY".

Comment: You can exchange your wrapper styles to `position: relative; width: 85%; float: right;` or something like that (you can change the `width` value). I'm not sure if it's what you want. I guess not. I don't think there is a proper solution for this. I'm not even know how do you want to make it look on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

To the first `div` that comes immediately after your `body` tag assign the following property:

```
left: 0;
```